# Detecting URL with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a website and I am needing help with a code that will evaluate to true if the URL is

**stackoverflow.com/users/anytext**

but not when the url is

**stackoverflow.com/users/**

Here is my code:

```css
<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div style = 'height:200px; width:200px; background-color: blue;' class = 'testbox' id = 'testbox'></div>
    <script>
        function storeurl() {
            var testbox = document.getElementById('testbox');
            varurl = document.URL; // it should be Global variable, so remove var
         
          
            if (varurl == 'file:///C:/Users/laptop%202/Desktop/test.html') { /* Need this to detect the url */
                if(!testbox.classList.contains('hidden')){
              testbox.classList.add("hidden");
          };
         }
            else {
             return varurl;
         };
        };
    
        document.onclick = storeurl;
    </script>
</body>
```

I am trying to accomplish this with pure Javascript. I was looking into Regular Expressions but without much luck.

Comment: `/stackoverflow\.com\/users\/.+/.test(url)`

Answer (score 1):

Without use of regex:

```js
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/";

var test1 = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/anything";
var test2 = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/";

console.log(test1.length > url.length && test1.startsWith(url));
console.log(test2.length > url.length && test2.startsWith(url));
```

(but maybe not as flexible as when use regex....)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
stackoverflow\.com\/users\/[^\s]+$
```

- You need to escape special characters like `.` and `/`
- `[^s]` matches anything except whitespace characters. You could also use anything here `.`
- `+` matches at least one of the preceding character (here `[\s]`)
- `$` end of the string

Here is an example in JavaScript:

```js
var regex = /stackoverflow\.com\/users\/[^\s]+$/
var text1 = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/";
var text2 = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/anything";

console.log(!!text1.match(regex));
console.log(!!text2.match(regex));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that is very informative. I am having issues getting it to work in the way I want though.  Basically what I am trying to do is grab the current url and compare the two in an if statement. if the url is for example stackoverflow/faculty/anytext it would hide an element. but if it is just stackoverflow/faculty/ it will show it

Comment: You can use `if(!!url.match(regex)) { //hide }` or `if(regex.test(url)) { // hide }}` whereas url is defined as `window.location.href`. Or with what part do you have problems?